# Editing text - how can I change cursor position?

Tags: qt, text

I have a `TextItem` inheriting `QGraphicsTextItem`. I am trying to get it to work based on specific requirements (center of transformations being center of bounding rectangle).

Since using `QGraphicsTextItem::paint()` gives me a little trouble (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255939/change-qgraphicstextitem-position-reference-to-the-center-of-bounding-rectangle)) and also because I will need special wrapping possibly, it would be ideal to draw text in `paint`.

```
 #include <QApplication>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsView>

class TextItem: public QGraphicsTextItem
{
public:
    TextItem()
    {
        QFont f;
        f.setPointSize(50);
        f.setBold(true);
        f.setFamily("Helvetica");
        setFont(f);
        setHtml("Caf&#x00e9; Frap&#x00e9;");
        setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable    |
                 QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable  |
                 QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
        setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::NoTextInteraction);
    }

    void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget)
    {
        qreal w = QGraphicsTextItem::boundingRect().width();
        qreal h = QGraphicsTextItem::boundingRect().height();
        QRectF r = QRectF(-w/2, -h/2, w, h);
        painter->setPen(QPen(m_penColor));
        painter->setFont(this->font());
        painter->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);

        painter->drawText(r, this->toPlainText(), this->document()->defaultTextOption());
    }

    QRectF boundingRect() const
    {
        qreal w = QGraphicsTextItem::boundingRect().width();
        qreal h = QGraphicsTextItem::boundingRect().height();
        QRectF r = QRectF(-w/2, -h/2, w, h);
        return r;
    }

protected:
    virtual void focusOutEvent (QFocusEvent * event)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(event);
        setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::NoTextInteraction);
    }
    virtual void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(event);
        setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction); 
        setFocus();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication  a(argc, argv);
    TextItem* t = new TextItem();
    QGraphicsView view(new QGraphicsScene(-200, -150, 400, 300) );
    view.scene()->addItem(t);
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

This works in drawing text with desired options, but I am unable to edit properly - the text cursor is always at the beginning of the text block.

How can I move text cursor ? Is it possible to attach it to the paint ?

Comment: I gave up and went back to QGraphicTextItem::paint() for now... If there is a solution for implementing cursor on the version with painter->drawText(), I would still appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to enable editing for the item like this:

```
setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditable);
```

You can then get the text cursor using the [textCursor()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicstextitem.html#textCursor-prop) function from QGraphicsTextItem and set it to any position u want, e.g.:

```
auto cursor = textCursor();
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
setTextCursor(cursor);
```

Update:

To edit based on the position of a double-click, you can reimplement the mouseDoubleClickEvent of QGraphicsTextItem like this:

```
void TextItem::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event)
{
    if (textInteractionFlags() == Qt::NoTextInteraction)
    {
        setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditable);
        setFocus();
    }

// ensure that when enabling the edit mode, the cursor is in an appropriate position (close to where the double-click happened)
    auto p = document()->documentLayout()->hitTest(event->pos(), Qt::FuzzyHit);
    auto cursor = textCursor();
    cursor.setPosition(p);
    setTextCursor(cursor);

    QGraphicsTextItem::mouseDoubleClickEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Updated question to include the linked portion about edit on double click.   If I don't use `QGraphicsTextItem::paint()`, then what do I apply the cursor to ? AS I mentioned in my question, and the code clearly shows, I am NOT calling  `QGraphicsTextItem::paint()`. If I was, the cursor would be positioned at the mouse coordinates and I would not have to move it. I want to implement that behavior. (or even `_cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::StartOfWord);` would be ok) - the problem is I DO NOT HAVE A WAY TO SET CURSOR. As my question title says.

Comment: Please check my update. This allows you to enter edit mode when double-clicking with the cursor being in the position of the double-click.

Comment: Thank you, the default behavior of QGraphicTextItem is that edit is at the cursor position. But since I have to implement my own paint, the cursor doesn't work anymore. That is the question.